# Is it possible to run application by clicking on its desktop-file from /usr/share/applications opened in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, icons, 19.10, .desktop, shortcuts

Just installed Nautilus on the Ubuntu MATE 19.10.
Navigated to `/usr/share/applications` to launch some application by clicking on its icon.
When I click on the icon of the desktop-file for application this file is opened in text editor.
Moreover the icons are not shown:

[image: Nautilus in 19.10]

How one can open application by clicking on its desktop-file in modern Nautilus?
I remember it was working as expected in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Not any more in 19.10. That's not the right place to start apps anyway, never was :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in modern versions of Nautilus. It is a [bug 1819375](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1819375) caused by upstream Nautilus [simplification](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/184).

You have to use other fully-functional modern file-managers like Caja, Dolphin, Konqueror, Nemo, PCManFM or Thunar.