# Default application for .desktop file

Tags: .desktop

What is the default application for opening .desktop file on Ubuntu 20.04 as originally intended? When I double-click, for example, firefox.desktop on /usr/share/applications, it opens as a text file on gedit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable default file manager(nautilus) to handle desktop icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263974/how-to-enable-default-file-managernautilus-to-handle-desktop-icons) and https://askubuntu.com/a/1231377/66509 .

Answer (score 0):

I've found by trial and error after 20 minutes. Right-click the .desktop file, click on "Properties", go to tab "Open With" and select "**Run Software**". Click the button "Set as Default" and close the window. Right-click again the .desktop file and click on "Allow Lauching". Jesus, I feel so dumb now; of course it's Run Software!

Thanks for the answer, it may help MATE desktop users who have the same problem.

Edit: the answer (that someone posted) related to MATE desktop was deleted.

Comment: MATE users do not have such problem at all. We can run any application from Caja showing /usr/share/applications path even on upcoming 21.04. Drop GNOME Shell (see [here how](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233026/66509)).

Comment: You apparently omitted to specify that your question relates to the Mate desktop. This answer may only be valid for Mate desktop, and thus is not a valid answer for the question as asked.

Comment: No, it was for default Ubuntu 20.04. There was a guy who posted an answer related to the question on MATE desktop, but he deleted the message.